# Proof of specific $n\times n$ matrix determinant result

Tags: matrices, determinant

I need to prove that for $n \times n$ matrix it holds that $D_n = n$, where
$$
D_n = 
\begin{vmatrix}
1       & -1    & -1    & \dots     & -1    \\
1       &  1    &       &           &       \\
1       &       &  1    &           &       \\
\vdots  &       &       & \ddots    &       \\
1       &       &       &           & 1    
\end{vmatrix}
$$
and all blank spaces are $0$.

I have calculated $D_n$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, 4$ using the method of minors and cofactors in order to see whether $D_n = n$ is true (it is) and I noticed that determinants of minors, as well as cofactors, can be either $1$ or $-1$.

Furthermore, using the method I mentioned, we have a sign pattern $+-+-+\dots$ for next cofactors. We always have then
$$\text{sign} \cdot \text{cofactor} \cdot \text{determinant of minor} = 1$$
which means that for $n\times n$ matrix and $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ minors, we have $D_n = \underbrace{1+\dots + 1}_{n} = n$, which is what I need to prove.

There are two problems with my (partial) solution: it is based on the observation for small $n$ values, which might not be true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and even if it was, the solution/proof is not formal. How could I generalize it for all $n$ and make it formally?

Comment: This is an example of arrowhead matrix for which there are many results, see the bible https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowhead_matrix

Comment: I read the whole page and sadly have not found anything helpful :(

Comment: You're right, but knowledge is always useful :). Indeed yours is a slightly generalized arrowhead matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the 2nd till the nth row to the first one and develop along the first row.
So, you get

$$D_n = 
\begin{vmatrix}
n       &  0   & 0    & \dots     & 0    \\
1       &  1    &       &           &       \\
1       &       &  1    &           &       \\
\vdots  &       &       & \ddots    &       \\
1       &       &       &           & 1    
\end{vmatrix} = n$$

Comment: It was quite a long time I did not have any contact with matrices and forgot the most basic operations, your answer helped me a lot and I see I need to recall everything. Thank you!

Comment: @whiskeyo You are welcome :-)